# FTB Infinity Evolved server not starting with JDK 8

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I have downloaded and unzipped the FTB Infinity server from [CurseForge](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/modpacks/ftb-infinity-evolved/files/2731545) on my Arch Linux machine and run both the install and run scripts, and I am presented with this error:

```java
Starting server
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using the ParNew young collector with the Serial old collector is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
A problem occurred running the Server launcher.java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.run(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:43)
    at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.ServerLaunchWrapper.main(ServerLaunchWrapper.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/Level
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:94)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.Level
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 8 more
```

My directory listing:

```bash
changelogs                 FTBserver.jar                ServerStart.sh
config                     libraries                    settings.bat
eula.txt                   minecraft_server.1.7.10.jar  settings.sh
FTBInstall.bat             modpack                      version.json
FTBInstall.sh              mods
FTBServer-1.7.10-1614.jar  ServerStart.bat
```

I looked at all of the questions online, and most of them said to install jdk 8, but I am already using it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is pretty dumb of the install script. It downloaded an XML file saying that the jar could not be found instead of the actual jar. (*laughs*) I should probably report that.